# Docker doesn't seem to be running. Did you start it?

Tags: bash, software-installation, docker, amazon-ec2

I try to install [DataHub](https://datahubproject.io/) together with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) on a t2.large [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) Instance running Ubuntu.

I am following a [installation guide for Docker](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-install-Docker-and-docker-compose-on-Ubuntu) and a [guide for DataHub](https://datahubproject.io/docs/quickstart/).
The tests proposed by the guides show me that both tools have been successfully installed.

My Docker installation:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-72:~$ sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.5
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.8
 Git commit:        bc4487a
 Built:             Wed Apr 26 16:21:07 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.5
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.8
  Git commit:       94d3ad6
  Built:            Wed Apr 26 16:21:07 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

My DataHub installation:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-72:~$ datahub version
DataHub CLI version: 0.10.2.2
Python version: 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]
```

The result if I try to use the command to start DataHub in Docker:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-72:~$ python3 -m datahub docker quickstart
[2023-05-12 06:27:11,109] INFO     {datahub.cli.quickstart_versioning:144} - Saved quickstart config to /home/ubuntu/.datahub/quickstart/quickstart_version_mapping.yaml.
[2023-05-12 06:27:11,109] INFO     {datahub.cli.docker_cli:643} - Using quickstart plan: composefile_git_ref='master' docker_tag='head'
Docker doesn't seem to be running. Did you start it?
```

My problem is that DataHub seems to not be able to use Docker. Can you please tell me how I can make DataHub find Docker?

I suspect that the quickstart command is searching for Docker in a location where Docker is not installed. I try to find and read through the code of the quickstart command in order to find the location it searches. Then I can compare that with the location where Docker is installed. However this will consume a lot of time and since this question is probably trivial and done in 5 min for a Linux Pro I humbly ask for your help.

Result of systemctl status docker:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-72:~$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-05-12 06:22:58 UTC; 46min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
   Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 639 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 10
     Memory: 102.2M
        CPU: 764ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
         └─639 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Comment: You're using a development version of Docker - can this be the issue?

Comment: Also what does `systemctl status docker` reveal?

Comment: @ArturMeinlid I added the result of systemctl status docker. I am still working on downgrading to another Docker version.

Comment: @ArturMeinild sorry, spelled your username wrong.

Comment: No problem. Hmm nothing unusual about the Docker service. Still, the only "odd" thing I can see is that you're running v.24rc2.

Comment: @ArturMeinild The version has been downgraded. I replaced the part in the description. The result is the same. Docker is not found.

Comment: Ok I'm not familiar with hot Datahub "detects" Docker running - but it clearly does not see the running service.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you, that at least confirms that it is a good idea to search the code of DataHub for how it tries to use Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Slack community from DataHub found the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhCue.png)

The `datahub docker quickstart` command can only work if Docker can be used without `sudo`.

Therefore it is necessary to follow this guide. It shows how you can create a usergroup for Docker. If Docker has a usergroup the `sudo` command is no longer neede.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

If somebody stumbles over this post who has deeper knowledge about why the usergroup is necessary a link or a short explanation would be much appreciated ;)